# Firebase Test lab Instrumented test error : NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, firebase, android-junit, firebase-test-lab

I'm trying to use Firebase Test Lab to run Instrumented Tests.

When I run local instrumented tests with android studio everything goes well.

When I upload APKs (app-debug.apk and app-debug-androidTest.apk) to Firebase test lab and run the instrumented test I go the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
 Process: com.ariase.********, PID: ****
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryNodeRenderer
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.doLoadClass(TestLoader.java:92)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.loadIfTest(TestLoader.java:113)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.loadClassesFromClassPath(TestRequestBuilder.java:801)
    at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:747)
    at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:354)
    at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:260)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1837)
```

Do you have an idea on what can cause this error?

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem, some annotations were missing on my classes...

```
@SmallTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class LoginActivityTest {
....
}
```

Thus, I don't understand why it was working in Android Studio without it...

**[EDIT]**
After some tests the error came back... Have you another idea?

**[EDIT 2]**
The error stopped when I added in the gradle the dependency:

```
compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
```

Comment: Annotations like SmallTest aren't strictly required.   But RunWith is important.